# Passport stamp when visiting multiple Schengen countries

Tags: air-travel, schengen, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, passport-stamps

I have a multiple entry Schengen visa for 1 year.
When I enter France from outside Schengen, I get a French entry stamp, right?
But if in France, after 10 days, I take a flight to Italy and I arrive there, will I get an Italian entrance stamp in my passport too? And when I take a plane from Italy to Denmark, will I get a Danish stamp too?
Once I leave Europe I will get the exit stamp in my passport from the country where I leave to my outside EU home country, right?

Comment: You will get *one* stamp once you enter the Schengen area in France. Flying on to Italy and Denmark, the flights are ‘domestic’, no systematic passport controls are performed and your passport won’t be restamped.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72064/is-it-possible-to-request-a-passport-stamp-when-traveling-between-schengen-count/72076#72076

Answer (score 11):

The Schengen Area Counts as a single country for border purposes, so when flying from France, to Italy, or Italy to Denmark, it's like a domestic flight, **no border control**. Just like when flying from Mexico City to Cancun.

So, you will get an entry stamp in France, and an exit stamp from the country where you exit Schengen to go back home.

Some Schengen countries (especially Switzerland) have random border checks when entering (but not exiting), but only at land borders and a few seaports (**not** airports), and even then passports are not stamped (even if you ask them to stamp, they cannot, because they have no stamps)